# How can I call AppleScript in a Swift file?

Tags: swift, applescript

I have the following Swift button, that once selected should run the following AppleScript to create a new note in the Mac Notes app.

```
@IBAction func selectButton(_ sender: Any) {
    
    let myAppleScript = """
         tell application "Notes"
             
             make new note at folder "Notes" with properties {name:"this is a test", body:"and more text"}
             
         end tell
  """
```

In my entitlements file I have the following

`<key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events <type>array <string>com.Apple.Notes</string>`

In my info.plist I have the following

`<key>Privacy - AppleEvents Sending Usage Description <string>Do you want to enable cross app usage?`

I don't understand why it isn't working, as I am creating an exception for the Notes app and sending a message to check in my info.plist file.

Comment: There are `NSAppleScript` and `NSUserAppleScriptTask` to run scripts.

Comment: You don’t say what error you get. Is Apple Events enabled under Hardened Runtime in Signing & Capabilities? [Example project here](https://github.com/hhas/Swift-AppleScriptObjC).

Comment: You just declared a String, but never said: use that into "AppleScriipt", you should have a warning "unused variable".